# draggable backgroun

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I want to achieve something like an infinite drag like the one in Konva js Can anyone help me with this. I try varius things but non of them were ok. Im new in p5js and javascript. Please for any hints. Only this element prevents me from completing the entire project.

```js
var grid;
var current_img;
var BgCat1 = [];
var layerOne;
let show_grid = false;
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do. Do you want the grid to be dragable like the example, infinitely?

Comment: yes.. i want grid to be draggable like the example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution, but here I draw an extra cell on each side of the grid to handle the wraparound, so a 12x12 grid with 10x10 visible. See it run here: https://editor.p5js.org/rednoyz/full/uJCADfZXv

```
let dim = 10, sz;
let xoff = 0, yoff = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  sz = width/ dim;
}

function mouseDragged() {
  xoff += mouseX - pmouseX;
  yoff += mouseY - pmouseY;
}

function draw() {
  background(255);

  for (let i = 0; i < dim+2; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < dim+2; j++) {

      let x = ((xoff + j * sz) % (width+sz)) - sz;
      if (x < -sz) x += width+sz;

      let y = ((yoff + i * sz) % (height+sz)) - sz;
      if (y < -sz) y += height+sz;

      rect(x, y, sz, sz);
      text(i * 10 + j, x + sz/2, y + sz/2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also put `if((mouseX < width && mouseX > 0)&&(mouseY < height && mouseY > 0))` on `mouseDragged()` function to work only on canvas dragging

Comment: anything else you are looking for in this answer, @michał-mi ?

Comment: I was responding to the questioner's request for additional code, which was later deleted